# How to load elements using eloquent according to policy?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, policy, laravel-collection

For example:
I defined (using policy) who can update post:

```
public function update(User $user, Post $post)
{
    return $user->id === $post->user_id;
}
```

And now i want to load (for example on user panel) all posts, that user can update.
I thought about filtering the collection of Posts using policy, but It'll be probably not effective when there'll be 500k posts.

Is there another way?

To clarify - this is just a simple example, policy rules will be much more complicated

Comment: Use policy only for the actual update of a post. For user panel list as update able posts with user_id.

Comment: @nikistag of course I can do it, but: I want to centralize rules (for policy and eloquent - same) and these rules will be more complicated than ->where('user_id', $id), for example  $user->superior can also edit post and $post->grantedUsers can edit and $post->grantedUser superiors. That's what I can reach - standardize and centralize.

Comment: If you don't want to display the posts to the users, I don't think policy is the right direction since the pagination would have the wrong number of items or you would have to load too much posts in memory. I would, personally, filter the posts with the database query. I would only use the policy to verify if the user as the permission to access the resource.